# A worker process serving application pool 'xxx v4.0 (Classic)' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit

Tags: c#, .net, iis, memory-management, application-pool

I have a shared hosting account with 128MB of RAM and my site is in its own app pool.

The site is small and gets low traffic, but I keep getting the following error:

```
A worker process serving application pool 'xxx v4.0 (Classic)' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.
```

This is happening frequently, which restarts the app pool. If the app pool restarts too often, eventually it will stop. Then I'll get a 503 error when I go to the site.

The site is written using c#, with data access from ef and ado.net. All my database connections are in using statements and I am confident they are being opened and closed correctly.

I have spoken to the host and I can upgrade the RAM to 256MB which does appear to make the site run nicely. But I am a bit concerned that just upgrading the RAM is only masking the problem temporarily.

Debug is set to false in the web config and I before I copy the files to the server I am building for release.

When I run the solution in visual studio my IIS Worker Process hovers around 100 MB.

**I think my questions are:**

Is there any way I can replicate my hosting environment on my local machine? 
Is it normal for a fairly small website to exceed 128MB of RAM?

I am at a bit of a loss of what to try. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Other potentially important info:**

.NET Framework is 4.5
Web Forms
AjaxControlToolkit is used (only the scripts I need are loaded)

I've looked at many blog posts and similar questions but I can't seem to make any progress.

Thanks

Jim

Comment: its a guess but I'd say you have a memory leak in your code. another guess would be check that you close all your database connections. change the code to use using statements if you are not already

Comment: guess two is static classes and methods

Comment: guess three is do you have any big datasets returned?

Comment: @Ewan, thanks for the advice! All db connections are in using statements, so I am happy they're fine. Have got a few static classes and methods, but not many. I will take a look and see if I can change those. No big datasets returned. Is it unusual for a website to use more than 128MB?

Comment: oo guess four, Session variables with shopping bags in. I guess 100Mb isnt huge, it really depends on your site. you have to think about how much stuff it holds open between requests usualy

Answer (score 0):

That message is about hitting the configured limit within IIS itself, it does not necessarily have anything to do with the amount of RAM on the host itself (although the settings you do set within IIS should take your aggregate RAM into account, so there is an indirect link).

- Open IIS
- Left Click on "Application Pools"
- Find your dedicated pool and right click on it, selecting "Recycling..."
- Check the "Private memory usage (in KB):" value
- That is what you are exceeding

[These instructions are based on IIS 7.5 but are similar for other versions]